# Duplicate Signature in @interface does not give compilation error

Tags: objective-c, interface

I have following @interface

```
@interface MyIterface
-(int) bar:(int)x1;
-(int) bar:(int)x2;
-(int) bar:(int)x3;
-(int) bar:(int)x4;
-(int) bar:(int)x5;
@end
```

I do not see any compilation error. Is it expected behavior in objective-c compiler?

Comment: That's very interesting. Presumably (since the parameter names aren't significant) the earlier declarations are just getting clobbered during class construction. Plain C doesn't seem to complain about multiple function declarations, either.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually including this interface anywhere? It very well should give you an error.

Comment: You may try yourself, I have a class that just implements this method once and I am able to call that method successfully. The formal parameter name in @implementation can be anything and does not have to be from x1 to x5.